# What Exception subclasses are built into PHP?

Tags: php, class, exception

I have not yet been able to find a list of all the built-in Exception sub classes in PHP.  I'd rather use built in ones when they make sense, before creating my own exception subclasses.

For example, I know InvalidArgumentException exists, but there appears to be nothing comparable to Java's NullPointerException.

Does anyone have or can link to a list of the available Exception subclasses in PHP?

Comment: PHP does not have NULL pointers. Trying to read an undefined variable is not an error and will result in merely a notice.

Comment: Actually, if dealing with objects, PHP can issue a `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object`. That would probably be the closest thing to a NullPointerException. Your instantiation/client code should be verifying object creation/validity. Beyond that you can set `set_error_handler`

Comment: @EmilVikström It may not be an error in PHP, but it is an error in the code logic which is the part of the reason to use exceptions.

Comment: @webbiedave Specifically I'm writing code that others will call into. I can't know that they'll be using my code correctly, and it wouldn't be my responsibility to correct the issue, merely to let them know they made a mistake. But the question is meant generally to get info about available exceptions.

Comment: I see. I thought you were trying to handle them. You're trying to find out what you can throw.

Comment: @webbiedave Exactly, I wanted to use built in exception types where I could. I'll make new exception types as they make sense, but even then, best to extend off of the existing ones.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

PHP 5 has two built in exceptions

- [`Exception`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php)
- [`ErrorException`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

Libraries within PHP have their own built in exceptions

- [`DOMException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domexception.php) DOM operations raise exceptions under particular circumstances, i.e., when an operation is impossible to perform for logical reasons.
- [`IntlException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlexception.php) his class is used for generating exceptions when errors occur inside intl functions. Such exceptions are only generated when intl.use_exceptions is enabled.
- [`PharException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pharexception.php) Thrown when working with the Phar class
- [`ReflectionException`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionexception.php) Thrown when working with Reflection classes

[SPL includes a few of its own built in exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php):

- [`BadFunctionCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badfunctioncallexception.php) A callback refers to an undefined function or if some arguments are missing.
- [`BadMethodCallException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php) A callback refers to an undefined method or if some arguments are missing.
- [`DomainException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php) A value does not adhere to a defined valid data domain.
- [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) The arguments passed were invalid.
- [`LengthException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.lengthexception.php) The parameter exceeds the allowed length (used for strings, arrays, file size, etc.).
- [`LogicException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php) Generic error occurred in program logic.
- [`OutOfBoundsException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php) An illegal index was requested.
- [`OutOfRangeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.outofrangeexception.php) An illegal index was requested. This represents errors that should be detected at compile time.
- [`OverflowException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.overflowexception.php) Adding an element to a full container.
- [`RangeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.rangeexception.php) Indicate range errors during program execution. Normally this means there was an arithmetic error other than under/overflow.
- [`RuntimeException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php) An error which can only be found on runtime occurs.
- [`UnderflowException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.underflowexception.php) Performing an invalid operation on an empty container, such as removing an element.
- [`UnexpectedValueException`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php) An unexpected value was received (i.e. as the result of a returned value from a method call).

PHP 7 introduces new exceptions including catchable errors. New exceptions include:

- [`Throwable`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement in PHP 7, including Error and Exception.
- [`Error`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) is the base class for all internal PHP errors.
- [`AssertionError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.assertionerror.php) is thrown when an assertion made via assert() fails.
- [`ParseError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.parseerror.php) is thrown when an error occurs while parsing PHP code, such as when eval() is called.
- [`TypeError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) There are three scenarios where a TypeError may be thrown. The first is where the argument type being passed to a function does not match its corresponding declared parameter type. The second is where a value being returned from a function does not match the declared function return type. The third is where an invalid number of arguments are passed to a built-in PHP function (strict mode only).
- [`ArithmeticError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.arithmeticerror.php) is thrown when an error occurs while performing mathematical operations. In PHP 7.0, these errors include attempting to perform a bitshift by a negative amount, and any call to intdiv() that would result in a value outside the possible bounds of an integer.
- [`DivisionByZeroError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php) is thrown when an attempt is made to divide a number by zero.
- [`ArgumentCountError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.argumentcounterror.php) is thrown when too few arguments are passed to a user-defined function or method.

PHP 7.3 introduces JSON exceptions:

- [`JsonException`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonexception.php) is thrown when `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` experience an error.

PHP 8 introduces one new exception:

- [`ValueError`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.valueerror.php) is thrown when you pass a value to a function, which has a valid type but can not be used for the operation.

[PHP 8.3 will add new exceptions for Date/Time errors](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/datetime-exceptions)

Here's a chart that demonstrates the new hierarchy introduced in PHP 7:

```
\Throwable
├── \Exception (implements \Throwable)
|   |── \DOMException (extends \Exception)
|   ├── \IntlException (extends \Exception)
|   ├── \JsonException (extends \Exception)
|   |── \PharException (extends \Exception)
|   |── \ReflectionException (extends \Exception)
|   |── \ValueError (extends \Exception)
│   ├── \LogicException (extends \Exception)
│   │   ├── \BadFunctionCallException (extends \LogicException)
│   │   │   └── \BadMethodCallException (extends \BadFunctionCallException)
│   │   ├── \DomainException (extends \LogicException)
│   │   ├── \InvalidArgumentException (extends \LogicException)
│   │   ├── \LengthException (extends \LogicException)
│   │   └── \OutOfRangeException (extends \LogicException)
│   └── \RuntimeException (extends \Exception)
│       ├── \OutOfBoundsException (extends \RuntimeException)
│       ├── \OverflowException (extends \RuntimeException)
│       ├── \RangeException (extends \RuntimeException)
│       ├── \UnderflowException (extends \RuntimeException)
│       └── \UnexpectedValueException (extends \RuntimeException)
└── \Error (implements \Throwable)
    ├── \AssertionError (extends \Error)
    ├── \ParseError (extends \Error)
    └── \TypeError (extends \Error)
        └── \ArgumentCountError (extends \TypeError)
    └── \ArithmeticError (extends \Error)
        └── \DivisionByZeroError extends \ArithmeticError)
```

Comment: Thanks John, but it's not a complete list. So I've created an answer with the links to the documentation that holds the info.

Comment: Going the extra mile and linking them all. Excellent.

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but for me it's kind of sad that 2.5 years after posting this answer, it was upvoted only 17 times.

Comment: @ex3v Think that's a comment on SO users, or on PHP devs?

Comment: @ex3v I don't bother signing into SO unless I want to comment so if it ever logs me out I can't vote unless I am going to comment.

Comment: I'm happy to see this answer has been kept up to date.

Answer (score 22):

Actually, I managed to find them now that I broke down and asked.

Technically it looks like PHP only has 2 built in exceptions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.exceptions.php

And the SPL Defines several more:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php

With an explanation of their heirarchy:
<strike>http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classException.html</strike>
[http://web.archive.org/web/20130829124146/http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classException.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20130829124146/http://www.php.net/%7Ehelly/php/ext/spl/classException.html) (archived on 29 Aug 2013)

**Update**

The link above is dead, it was a diagram of the basic PHP exception hierarchy.  I couldn't find the original, but here's a replacement:

[image: PHP Exception Hierarchy]

Originally found at http://fossies.org/dox/php-5.2.17/classException.html, now archived at http://web.archive.org/web/20151002165210/https://fossies.org/dox/php-5.2.17/classException.html (archived on 02 Oct 2015)

Comment: @Hirnhamster Thanks, included an image to replace the dead link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script, runnable online, that will show the exception hierarchy for every PHP version where the output differs:

https://3v4l.org/sDMsv

I didn't write the code. It was found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php#120776