# What built-in exception to use for requiring a method to be called?

Tags: php, exception

Say you want to require a certain method to be called first before calling another. Is there an appropriate built-in exception for that? E.g.,

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar;

    public function getBar()
    {
       if (!$this->bar)
          throw new Exception('must call setBar() first');

        return $this->bar;
    }

    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;    
    }
}
```

What built-in exception is an appropriate replacement for the generic `Exception` in this example?

Comment: [What Exception subclasses are built into PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838257/what-exception-subclasses-are-built-into-php)

Comment: Not sure how you would fit the standard ones into your case, but I would have thought that it was more a case of not having a value to return exception (although that may just be an example)

Comment: @NigelRen Yeah it's a generic example but I'm looking for recommendations for similar cases. Maybe `BadMethodCallException` or `UnexpectedValueException`?

Comment: Not sure but perhaps [DomainException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official exception hierarchy for php7

http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php

---

*Exceptions that catch my attention are*

### `LogicException`

- Exception that represents error in the program logic. This kind of
  exception should lead directly to a fix in your code.

### `BadMethodCallException`

- Exception thrown if a callback refers to an undefined method or if
  some arguments are missing.

---

`BadMethodCallException` doesn't quite seem to fit, while `LogicException` sounds like the best of all built in exceptions.